# Unprivileged reboot?

Tags: arch-linux, privileges

```
$ uname -a
Linux msi 5.8.14-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 07 Oct 2020 23:59:46 +0000 x86_64 GN>
```

so I do a console login as a regular user, type `reboot` and it works. `shutdown now` as well.

Why am I not required to be `root` to do that like on `debian`?

Comment: Why are using [tag:arch-linux] but asking about Debian?

Comment: He's not asking about Debian, he claims that you need to be root on Debian which is incorrect.

Comment: It is weird to me to be able to terminate every users' sessions without privileges. Alas, this is the answer: "`logind` is asked to perform the action, using `polki`t actions `org.freedesktop.login1.*`"